# performance vs security in PHP (firebug s/w can bypass values)

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, yii, firebug

this is something that came up to mind suddenly... so would like to know what is the best practice to handle and to know the security capacity of major PHP frameworks..

suppose a set of users are there in a developed web application.. (in users module).. each of the registered users will have privileged based tasks to do based on their rights and access levels...

Now since we have many free front end debuggers like firebug and etc... i am wondering 
using firebug if the user can get the ID of lets say super admin..... (lets assume, this as the user_id of user table for super admin user(s) )  this is taken, may be by referring the hidden field values or however somewhere from the system......

Now, there is a chance that he(current user) might change the user id to 1 (lets say '1' is super user) using fire bug and submit a certain form..

ex:  a form that contains to allow some permission to users to do some actions in the system.. let me say its like 'create a post' (checkbox or dropdown) and then a another dropdown is there to select the user that he is willing to assign (only some users of the system are visible to this user to assign.. since he is a mid privileged.. so the super uses are not there ) but now lets say he knows the user id's of those super levels and he is changing the selected value of a certain user...  lets say he selects a user who has id = 101... in the dropdown value it becomes like this...   Normal User ... now with the help of firebug '101' is changed to one of super user's id..... '1' or '2' or '3'..... so this allows overriding as i tried doing a similar change and got upset how come this could be possible...

so how would we handle such a situation with best practices is my dilemma...

i see the only way is to handle this is...

to check before saving weather the data we received on form submit is the same data we had on from load and then let them save or else throw and error....  to do this,  some performance will get involved and i am not sure is this a practical and best thing to do......

At least i would like to know is any PHP framework's does protection from this kind of a thing ? i would rather say attack..

Please let me know this from PHP geeks... not sure weather this is a possible thing to happen in other programming languages.. as i am PHP developer i just wanted to know in related to PHP terms...

FYI,  i am using Yii framework for my development work........ and also at times will use codeignitor framework.

Comment: Users are a bunch of evil genius hell bent on breaking your app and making you look like a moron. Never trust them.

Comment: What Orangepill wants to say with this rabble-rousing words is that you **must always** verify the data coming from the client on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, there is a chance that he(current user) might change the user id
>   to 1 (lets say '1' is super user) using fire bug and submit a certain
>   form..

It is totally wrong to rely on client's data. Basically, you store the login data in SESSION (such as user_id), not in HTML form. However, by storing everything in SESSION does not stop bad user from gaining unauthorized access ([Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)). It just make it more difficult.

> At least i would like to know is any PHP framework's does protection
>   from this kind of a thing ? i would rather say attack..

PHP Framework does not protection you from attack, it is your job to protect your software. However, it is not very difficult to strengthen your application security. The following is a chart of common attack.

- Cross Site Scripting, 37%
- SQL Injection, 16%
- Path Disclosure, 5%
- Denial of Service, 5%
- Code Execution, 4%
- Memory Corruption, 4%
- Cross Site Request Forgery, 4%
- and more

**Prevention**

- SQL Injection: Do not manually concatenate SQL query. Use PDO and prepare statement.
- Cross Site Scripting: Use `htmlspecialchars` to display any our user input.
- Code Execution: Don't use `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

imho minimally seems like you should have a basic auth mechanism, whether security tokens, cookies/sessions, if the user tells the system its own id, this is a pretty obvious pitfall. furthermore firebug is 1 simple tool, scripted queries would make it trivial to try ids 1 to 1000000 astonishingly quick.

1 way, basic/digest auth & code segmentation, using require user group to prevent access to this script at apache level. not much code change involved. tokens would be my approach, generating a token to validate form data, preventing users/firebug/scripted queries but requires a bit more cpu processing / subject to hammering.

cookies/sessions might work as well, purely depends on your environment.
i've experienced all 4 scenarios to work equally well depending on context, that said, if you can avoid loading any php at all [apache level only] seems to be best against hammering/bruteforce attempts if there's no security mechanisms to prevent them from exhausting server connections.